# I get different output when I run the same code on different consoles using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function guns() {
    console.log(this.had);
}

var had ="guts";

var stun = {
    had : "cuts",
    guns: guns

};

var murn = {
    had : "mork"
};

guns();

stun.guns();

guns.call( murn );

new (guns);
```

I used this code in visual code studio and my browsers console, but when I run the code in these two places the result is different. In in my browsers console I get guts, cuts, mork, and undefined. In visual studios code I get undefined, cuts, mork, and undefined. Why does this happen? I'm new to javascript and programming and this is very confusing to me. I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Simple answer is to do `console.log(this)` ... will see it is  different in the two environments. Read up on how `this` works. Not hard to find lots of information on it

Comment: Different UIs / Layers. If your are posting to web, test your JS in browser console.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use `this` in a function that isn't being called on an object.

Comment: Use `had = "guts"` instead of `var had = "guts"` to make it a global variable in all environments, or use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so that `this` itself is `undefined` in the `guns()` call as proper.